# How can I highlight unmatched HTML tags in Emacs?

Tags: html, emacs, elisp, flymake

I'd really like to catch unbalanced HTML tags as I edit HTML snippets inside Emacs. For example, JSFiddle offers this:

[image: jsfiddle highlighting tags]

I've found that there's also a [wrapper for weblint](http://user42.tuxfamily.org/weblint/index.html) but that only support HTML 4.

[flycheck support HTML checking](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck#features) using tidy, but that assumes the current buffer is a complete HTML page. I often edit templates which are included in other templates, so my buffer rarely has a `<html>` or a `<head>` in it.

How can I highlight unbalanced HTML tags, without writing full HTML documents?

Comment: My appologies I did not read your question carefully enough.
I did write an answer with an recommendation of nxml-mode.
When I came back here, I noticed that you want to check a partial html document.
And when I checked nxml-mode with a partial html document it marked many tags as erroneous.

Comment: Does the buffer only contain the html-fragment or also other text? In the latter case how is(are) the html-fragment(s) separated from the other text? Are there special strings as limiters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: To avoid concurrent versions the code is maintained only at:

**http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/html-check-frag.el**

Please, apologize for any inconveniences caused by this decision.

---

The old description was:
Edit: I did some bug-fixing, and I've also [uploaded the file to emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/html-check-frag.el).

You can try the following. New and surely buggy. But, maybe it is better than nothing.
Execute the lisp code, switch to the buffer with the html-fragment and activate the minor mode html-check-frag-mode.

... And here was the *outdated code*. ...

Comment: Wow, that works really well. The only thing it needs to be perfect is to skip [void elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements) such as `<br>` which don't need to be closed.

Comment: Empty element nodes are to be written as <br/>. This is regarded by the code. Illegal constructs that are accepted by browsers such as <p>bla<br>blob</p> could be added. This would not be too difficult. But, I am busy at the moment. The code at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HtmlCheckFrag is the compensation for the first unqualified (and deleted) answer. But, parsing illegal syntax is extra stuff.

Comment: Perhaps tonight... (requires list of exceptional keywords, has to be supplied by the user could be compiled from html-tag-alist, may be implemented directly into html-check-frag-region).

Comment: In HTML 5, void tags do not have to be closed -- [see section 8.1.2.1.6 of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags). But anyway, I don't want to be negative about a brilliant piece of code that makes my life easier :).

Comment: Thaks for the info. Now, I have a list (area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr). I'll add it as soon as possible.

Comment: Next version does not test matching void tags. Could you test http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/html-check-frag.el.gz ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One more comment. I think we should remove the elisp-section from the answer since it is old code and the new code cannot be pasted here (don't know why). I wanted to put the source code in text form on emacswiki.org. This also failed. The gzip-archive at emacswiki.org was the only thing that worked. Are you fine with deleting the emacs-section? We keep the link to emacswiki.org.

Comment: I've updated the code in your answer and changed the copy on the wiki to use the .el version. I can also confirm that void tags are correct. Huge thanks :).

Comment: There were spurious TAG errors. I've corrected this issue in http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-de/html-check-frag.el. We should replace the above source code by a link to emacs-wiki. This would be the most simple way to keep the answer up-to-date. Are you fine with that?

Comment: yep, I'm fine with that. It's better to have a single canonical home for the code.

Comment: I've requested added this great package to MELPA: https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa/pull/3414

Comment: Would you mind putting the source code on GitHub somewhere @tobias? I'd love to add this package to MELPA, but they don't support emacswiki any more. See the pull request above.

Comment: @WilfredHughes I've never put something on GitHub. I will see whether I find time. It is on my todo list. But I am currently rather busy.

Comment: @WilfredHughes See https://github.com/TobiasZawada/html-check-frag. Best regards, Tobias

Answer (score 0):

If flycheck+tidy works for full pages then you can write an elisp function which is called when the file is saved, so that it pops up a temporary buffer with your file contents and with `<head>` and other necessary stuff added to it and then turns on flycheck in that temporary buffer, so you can see if there are unmatched tags.

It's not instant on the fly error highlighting, but at least you'll see the errors when you save the file.

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that it won't work on buffers that contain full HTML documents.

Comment: @Wilfred Hughes: why shouldn't it? For full documents you simply don't add the missing body/head tags which you add for partial documents. Or if you detect it's a full document then you turn on flycheck directly in the buffer and skip the whole checking at save thing. It shouldn't be hard to decide if it's a full document or partial one and choosing the appropriate method automatically.