# XHTML: how to highlight matching tag?

Tags: emacs, xhtml, syntax-highlighting

I'd like highlighting of the matching HTML tag when the cursor is on the specific tag.

I'm looking for something like `highlight matching parentheses` in `options` menu.

I've checked the question [How can I highlight unmatched HTML tags in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363837/how-can-i-highlight-unmatched-html-tags-in-emacs?rq=1) which is close to what I search but I want highlight of *all* the matching tags (where the cursor is), not only the errors.

Comment: How about this related thread entitled **Emacs matching tags highlighting**?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7784334/2112489

Comment: I should have searched better... Thanks, it's solved!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[web-mode](http://web-mode.org/) provides this. You can enable with `web-mode-toggle-current-element-highlight`

Comment: It's only a matter of taste, but I prefer the script given by @lawlist in the comment (colors are right, out of the box). But since it was the only answer and it's good too...

Comment: It's acceptable to answer your own question and accept it. If you would prefer you can write a version of that stackoverflow answer here and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> [web-mode](http://web-mode.org/) provides this. You can enable with `web-mode-toggle-current-element-highlight`

You can add `(setq web-mode-enable-current-element-highlight t)`
into your web-mode-hook to make this behavior persistent.